# 'this' is undefined in class

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous

Have a look at the code follows.

I am creating a class with a constructor in which I am creating some variables. Furthermore I am creating some asynchronous functions, of which 3 are very similar and the last one is able to call the others.

```
class Project {
    data = {};
    constructor(project, api) {
        for (const key in project) {
            this.data[key] = project[key];
        }
        this.logger = new Logger(
            document.querySelector("#output"),
            `Project= ${this.data.projectId}: `
        )
        this.api = api;
    }
    async getTasks() {
        return await this.api.getTasksAsync(this.projectId);
    }
    async getRequirements() {
        return await this.api.getRequirementsAsync(this.projectId);
    }
    async getReleases() {
        return await this.api.getReleasesAsync(this.projectId);
    }
    async getToDraw(type) {
        let func = this[`get${type}`];
        console.log(func);
        let result = [];
        for (let item of await func()){
            result.push(toTaskItem(item));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The error I get when executing the function 'getToDraw' on an initiated object of the class 'Project' (above):
[image: Error Pic]

I am calling the function as follows:

```
async drawDiagram(sender){
    let projectID = this.getSelectedValue("projectSelector");
    if (projectID !== "-1") {
        let project = this.projects.filter((project) => project.data.ProjectId === parseInt(projectID))[0];
        if (document.querySelector("#typeSelector").selectedOptions[0].innerText === "Full"){
            // TODO: 
        } else {
            let list = await project.getToDraw(document.querySelector("#typeSelector").selectedOptions[0].innerText);
            console.log(list);
        }
    } else {
        for (let project of this.projects) {
            // TODO:
        }
    }
}
```

If no one knows a solution for me, I already know how I could do it in another way, but I would like to do it like this...

Gracias, guys.

Comment: How do you call the method?

Comment: How do you instantiate your object and how do you call the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this line

```
let func = this[`get${type}`];
```

It unbinds (or 'disconnects') the function from the `this` reference to the class so that when you call `func()`, `this` becomes `undefined`.

There are a couple ways to get around this. You could re-bind `this` using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), like this:

```
let func = this[`get${type}`].bind(this);
```

Or you could explicitly rebind the methods within the constructor:

```
class Project {
  constructor(project, api) {
    ...
    this.getTasks = this.getTasks.bind(this);
    this.getRequirements = this.getRequirements.bind(this);
    this.getReleases = this.getReleases.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Or you could define your methods as lambda expression properties, like this:

```
class Project {
  data = {};
  getTasks = () => { ... };
  getRequirements = () => { ... };
  getReleases = () => { ... };
}
```

These are not the only solutions, of course, and they may have some different side-effects. For example, the lambda expression properties are enumerable, so they will appear in `Object.keys(new Project())`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because when you store the `getRequirements` method in the `func` variable, you separate it from its context.

You have to reattach again the `this` context to `func`.

#### First way: attach context only once

You just have to call the `func` function like this:

```
func.call(this); // call func with this as context
func(); // call func with undefined context
func.call({}); // call func with empty object as context
```

This way, you force calling `func` with `this` as context.

#### Second way: attach context for all future calls

You have to `bind` a new context before calling the function:

```
func(); // call func with undefined context
func = func.bind(this);
func(); // call func with this as context
func(); // recall func with this as context
```

This way, you link `this` as new context for `func`.

Comment: Or you can just call the method and not put it in a variable `this['get${type}']()`